# Use of „als wolle“ in imaginary comparisons

Tags: conjunction, modal-verb

Learning about the use cases for the verb *wollen*, I came across the use of “*als wolle*” for imaginary comparisons –

> Es scheint, als wolle die Begeisterung der Reisenden über den neuen
> Terminal 1 nicht abebben.
>
> Willem lächelte sie an und tauchte in ihre Augen, als wolle er in
> ihnen ertrinken.

Till now, I have only seen “*als ob*” used for this purpose and none of my grammar books mention it.  Is this a colloquial or regional usage?

Source: https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=als+wolle+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is nothing special or unusual. It just is *Konjunktiv I.* You use it in these situations:

- indirect speech

  > Tom twittert, er **tränke** gerade ein Bier.
  > Lisa sagt häufig, sie **ginge** gar nicht so gern einkaufen.
  > Dr. Steiner teilte uns gestern mit, er **wolle** das Unternehmen demnächst verlassen.
- wishes (often in fixed phrases)

  > Lang **lebe** der König
  > Dein Reich **komme,** dein Wille **geschehe.**
- in recipes

  > Man **nehme** drei Eier und **verrühre** sie.

---

A sub-form of indirect speech is reported speech. This is when you observe something and want to tell it in a way, that the reader knows, this is what you observed, although there is a small chance, that the reporter has been tricked and in fact something else is happening.

> Es hat den Anschein, als **tränke** Tom gerade ein Bier.
> It seems as if Tom was drinking a beer.
> I can see him thinking something, and what is in the glass looks pretty much like beer, but I didn't check, if it really is beer. There is a little chance, that he is drinking something else. Maybe there also is a little chance, that it isn't Tom but some other guy who just looks like Tom.

> Es sieht so aus, also **ginge** Lisa gar nicht so gern einkaufen.
> It looks as if Lisa does not like shopping at all.
> This is what I observed, but maybe Lisa love shopping, I just haven't seen her doing it very often.

> Es scheint, als **wolle** Dr. Steiner das Unternehmen demnächst verlassen.
> It seems that Dr. Steiner wanted to leave the company soon.
> He was seen removing his private things from the office and there is a rumor that he received a very tempting offer from a competitor. But whether this step is really what he wants for himself is speculation.

---

You can use Konjunktiv I with full verbs ...

> Es scheint, als **backe** deine Mutter einen Kuchen.
> Es hat den Anschein, als **brenne** der Wald.
> Es wirkt, als **liefe** dein Hund auf nur drei Beinen.

... auxiliary verbs ...

> Es schien, als **habe** deine Mutter einen Kuchen gebacken.
> Es hatte den Anschein, als **habe** der Wald gebrannt.
> Es wirkte, als **sei** dein Hund auf nur drei Beinen gelaufen.

... and modal verbs

> Es scheint, als **solle** deine Mutter einen Kuchen backen.
> Es hat den Anschein, als **müsse** der Wald brennen.
> Es wirkt, als **wolle** dein Hund auf nur drei Beinen laufen.

Comment: To clarify - Aren't "hätte" and "wäre" in Konjunktiv II?  I would have used "habe" and "sei" for Konjunktiv I.  Many thanks for the detailed reply!  It will take me a while to digest it all! :)

Comment: @SatishVasan: You are right, I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: "tränke" is ebenfalls Konjunktiv II, it should be "trinke"

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit hard to understand, because it is a somewhat high-tone construction, which is not used very often in every-day German. Here, *wolle* is the 3rd Person Singular, Present Subjunctive (Konjunktiv I) form of *wollen*.

The sentence would literally translate to something like:

> It seems, as if the enthusiasm [...] wouldn't want to ebb away.

The construction using a modal subclause with the conjunction *als* and a Konjunktiv verb is not limited to *wollen*. It indicates a *Potentialis* (a possible hypothesis), while the construction with *als ob* indicates an *Irrealis* (an impossible hypothesis): It expresses less distance to that hypothetis, than the construction with *als ob*; *als ob* is basically saying that the hypothetical is not actual, the construction with *als* and Konjunktiv leaves more space for the hypothesis to be actually true.

The most famous example I can think of is in the poem [*Mondnacht*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondnacht_(Eichendorff)) by Joseph von Eichendorff:

> Und meine Seele spannte /
> Weit ihre Flügel aus /
> Flog durch die stillen Lande /
> Als flöge sie nach Haus

Comment: I somehow miss the term [Irrealis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis), because it seems to me, that subjunctive is just the vehicle, not the concept, even if the German *Möglichkeitsform* at least hints at the issue.

Comment: @guidot I don't think that the construction with _als_ + Konjunktiv is an Irrealis. It is a Potentialis. However, thanks for mentioning this. I am adding it.

Comment: Many thanks to Jonathan and guidot for the distinction between Potentialis and Irrealis.  It really helps!